# How to create View of three tables with relations in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, aggregate-functions, sql-view

I have three tables, the first one about products, the second about authors and the third table illustrates which product is related to which author. The reason that I have three tables is that a product can have more than one author.

```
product : 
id  |   name   |   price

user :
id   |   name   

user_product :
product_id   |   user_id
```

now I want to create a view which includes id, name and price from the product table and "name" from user table, so that if there are more than one authors, their names are separated with a comma.

```
view_product :
id   |   product_id   |   product_name   |   product_price   |   user_name
```

I would appreciate it very much if anyone can help me with writing this query.

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY.

Comment: Note that queries against VIEWs in MySQL cannot access underlying indexes, rendering their usefulness questionable. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses a correlated subquery and string aggregation function `group_concat()`:

```
create view myview as
select p.id as product_id, p.name as product_name, p.price as product_price,
    (
        select group_concat(u.name)
        from user_product up
        inner join user u on u.id = up.user_id
        where up.product_id = p.id
    ) as user_names
from product p
```

You can also join and aggregate:

```
create view myview as
select p.id as product_id, p.name as product_name, p.price as product_price,
    group_concat(u.name) as user_names
from product p
left join user_product up on up.product_id = p.id
left join user u on u.id = up.user_id
group by p.id
```